# Div scrolling over fixed div anchor link not working

Tags: css

I am using this code for a site I am developing. The problem I am having is scrolling up to the fixed panel div.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="a" class="panels">FIXED PANEL</div>
    <div id="b" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 1</div>
    <div id="c" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 2</div>
    <div id="d" class="panels"><a href="#a">Scrolling-Panel 3</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:black;
}

#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.panels {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#a{
   background:#eee;
    position:fixed;
    color:red;
    top:0;
}

#b{
   margin-top:100%;
   background:yellow;
}

#c{
   background:pink;
}

#d{
   background:green;
}
```

Fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ygw6b9ga/
Any ideas/help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Just so you know, @username highlights don't work like that on Stack Overflow. Please try explaining your problem, most of us will have zero clue what you're trying to do.

Comment: The legend property does not work for bottom to top. it will work top to bottom: see the jsfiddle Fixed panels with scrolling panel2 see :  http://jsfiddle.net/ygw6b9ga/2/

Comment: myf's solution is working well for me

Comment: @Janine So was it sufficient? If so, you can mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @myf Yes sufficient - I have marked your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking link anchor targeting different element in page tells browser to scroll viewport or corresponding wrapper so elements upper left corner (in LTR page) is visible. Fixed elements does not affect scrolling areas so targeting and focussing them does not initiate this routine.

In your example you could either target the #wrapper instead of the #a to re-reveal fixed header (`<a href="#wrapper">…</a>`, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40ef0f1c/)) or resort to javascript (`<a href="#a" onclick="scrollTo(0,0)">…</a>` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h89h19sw/)).